# PHP retrieving database row counts and executing a file

Tags: php, sql, cron

I have a simple question. I‘d like to write a php function to check the database rows and if the number of rows are affected by the last ran query, execute an internal php file. The catch is, that I want it to check the rows, and check the timestamp at the same time so if the time stamp is different and the row count is different, it executes the php file.
The file in question is a sql database backup, so I need it to only execute if there was a change in the database and if the time stamp is older than 43200 seconds (half a day). This would backup the database if there was activities on the site (one activity would back once, two activity would back up twice and anything more than that would be ignored), and if not, it would not do anything. I hope I’m explaining it right.
Cron job is out of question, since it’s dependant on the database changes not just the time.

The code I’m using is like this (without checking the database rows) and is only accessed when a customer access the shopping cart checkout or account page:

```
<?php
$dbbackuplog = '/path/to/backuptime.log';
if (file_exists($dbbackuplog)) {
$lastRun = file_get_contents($dbbackuplog);
if (time() - $lastRun >= 43200) {
     //Its been more than 12 hours so run the backup
     $cron = file_get_contents('/file.php');

     //update backuptime.log with current time
     file_put_contents($dbbackuplog, time());
    }
}
?>
```

I appreciate any input or suggestions.

Comment: I would question why you are looking to implement your own backup strategy. Have you investigated what backup tools there are for the database you are using. If it's MySQL, have you looked into binary logging, replication, mysqldump, mysqlhotcopy etc?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot run anything with `file_get_contents`. That function simply reads the bare contents of the file you ask for and under no circumstances will it run any code. If you want to run the code, you want `include` or `require` instead.

Second, your idea about not just triggering but also *fully executing* backups while a customer is performing an action is, well, I 'm not going to pull any punches, *terrible*. There's a reason why people use cron for backups (actually more than one reason) and you should follow that example. That's not to say that you are not allowed to affect the behavior of the cron script based on dynamic factors, but rather that *the act of taking a backup* should *always* be performed behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for your replies and suggestions. The reason that I'm trying to use the customers to trigger the backup is that it would simplify the installations and most importantly would run on Linux and windows servers.

The `file_get_contents` doesn't really read the file as the file is empty. Its purpose is to check the time and nothing else. Once the conditions are met, the database will get backed up, compressed and emailed out. I can't think of any way that it would affect the customer experience any differently than if I started a backup manually in the back-end. 
Thanks again.

Comment: @Chris81: Write a "backup procedure" that does `sleep(20)`, pretend you are a user and trigger it. See what happens.

Comment: Jon, that would halt everything for 20 seconds. Are you saying that running the backup like that stops everything from loading until it's done?

Comment: @Chris81: What I 'm actually saying is that you should experience it first hand since it's so easy to do, but yes.

Comment: That does makes scene. So how can I trigger the backup by the users and not hangup the site until the back up is done? (Without Cron of course)